# How to put 2 pictures next to each other without moving when adding more text in div?

Tags: css, html, row, image

I just started to design a small Webpage to present some designs.
It's **a page with 2 columns, with a picture and some text for each.**

The problem I have right now: when I add more text to one column, the picture of the other column moves.

**Check out my fiddle:** 
 http://jsfiddle.net/JannikS/tMY57

My HTML markup:

```
  <div id="designrow"> 
      <div class="design"> 
            <img src="http://www.webdesign-is-art.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/goodbytes-webdesign.jpg" />          
            <h3>Title </h3> 
            <p>Short description of our design..</p>             
      </div>     
      <div class="design"> 
            <img src="http://www.webdesign-is-art.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/goodbytes-webdesign.jpg" />          
            <h3>Title </h3> 
          <p>Short description of our design..<br /> but with some more text!</p>             
      </div>   
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.designrow { 
 float: left;   }

.design {   
 width: 300px; 
 margin-left: 20px; 
 margin-right: 20px; 
 margin-bottom: 20px; 
 display: inline-block;
  }  

.design img{ 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're giving your columns `display:inline-block`, remove that and `float:left` instead

heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tMY57/3/